# Track edX or Udemy course progress using an API

Tags: api, tracking, edx

Is there a way to track user's progress on edX or Udemy through an API?

I am trying to aggregate different courses for a certain track and would like to track the user's progress throughout the course so I can show them to the instructor.

Is it something possible?

> I found an API for edX:   https://courses.edx.org/api-docs/
>
> I found an API for Udemy: https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/

but both can't track progress.

Comment: The `completion` section on edX isn't what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Udemy, try `GET /api-2.0/courses/{pk}/` and according to the documentation [here](https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/models/course/) it returns a list of courses that contains amount of course completion for each course.

For edx, you can use `GET /completion/v1/subsection-completion/{username}/{course_key}`.

Comment: This does not work for Udemy as of now, you dont get any information about course progress

Answer (score 1):

For edx:
Use `/completion/v1/subsection-completion/{username}/{course_key}/(P{subsection_id}[/]*)`.
For udemy, I dont know.